# fail to print href on my excel workbook by selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

i can't print href on my excel workbook
my code looks ok, and it works when print title and date on my excel workbook,
but href column just dont work,
plz help me, thanks.

```
# Intel newsroom
driver.get('https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/newsroom/home.html#gs.4bhcva')
sleep(2)

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = workbook['test']
mxR = sheet.max_row
nowrow = mxR + 1  # Start from the next row after existing data
eles = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'content-headline')
for ele in eles[:3]:  # Print the first 3 elements
    title = ele.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'title').text
    href = ele.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'title').get_attribute('href')
    date = ele.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'article-date').text
    
    sheet.cell(row=nowrow, column=1).value = 'Intel newsroom'
    sheet.cell(row=nowrow, column=2).value = title
    sheet.cell(row=nowrow, column=3).value = href
    sheet.cell(row=nowrow, column=4).value = date
    nowrow += 1  # Move to the next row

workbook.save('test.xlsx')

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause:** `href` attribute is on the `<a>` node. But your below line of code is locating `<h3>` node.

```
href = ele.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'title').get_attribute('href')
```

**Solution:** Change the above line to:

```
href = ele.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='title']//a").get_attribute('href')
```